# camera snapping weirdly when aligning to view

Tags: unity, transformation

The **apply** word above comes from 'blender 3D'. Basically, once you rotate an object , it's x, y, z value changes. What **apply** does is keep the transformation, but, change the x, y, z value back to 0.

Is this possible in unity? How do I do this?

EDIT: I've basically created a player rig, and inside it the camera is nested. Since the camera is rotated 90deg inside it's parent, when I do : **GameObject>Align with view**, the camera ends up rotating 90 deg elsewhere, the gif is shown [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lR62l.jpg)(I tried but couldn't embed this image here)

Comment: This is not an operation that's typically performed in Unity. You usually set up the relationship between the object's internal coordinate system and its global orientation in your Digital Content Creation software (like a 3D modelling program), then import that asset into Unity with the correct relationship already "applied". Can you tell us more about how you're wanting to use this in your game? We might be able to suggest a corresponding way to achieve that objective.

Comment: To add to @DMGregory's comment, it took me a bit to "get" this as well.  Remember that when using transform controls in Unity you are transforming the GameObject, not the Mesh itself.  In Blender (or other modeling apps), you are working directly with the Mesh.  It's useful to think in terms of a GameObject as a container in Unity.  If you put a cube inside a box, then rotate the box, the cube inside doesn't change (in relationship to the box) but does change in relationship to the world _because_ it's container changed.

Comment: @DMGregory , I am trying to align my camera to scene view, but, when I do GameObject>Align with View, the camera rotates 90 degress and I'm having a hard time aligning it. Don't know why this is happening, so I was experimenting here and there, the camera is rotated 90 degree, but, it's parent is not, so when I'm selecting the parent and "Align with view", I should snap the camera to view, but, it rotates. (The camera is rotated 90 deg to align the camera axes with it's parent)

Comment: @juztcode - with nested GameObjects, remember that the same applies for all transform (position, rotation, and scale).  If you put a 1x1x1 cube into a gameObj1, and put gameObj1 into gameObj2, rotation gameObj2 will rotate everything under it.  Scaling gameObj2 will also scale everything under it.  This can get confusing with nested objects if you aren't paying close attention, but can also be very useful for building complex scenes.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to edit your question to ask about that specific use case, "How do I align my camera with my view," and include a description (with screenshots/diagrams) explaining how your camera and its parent object(s) are set up. Showing the unwanted symptoms you're getting currently can help too. With this info, folks should be able to tailor a solution that works smoothly in that particular context.

Comment: @DMGregory, gotcha, just a sec.

Comment: @DMGregory, I've posted the link to live demo above. Sorry, couldn't embed it into the question itself

Comment: Don't forget to edit the *text* of your question, including the title. Videos don't help with accurate search indexing, screen readers, etc.

Comment: @DMGregory , done